# How do I merge a list of results into a compacted object with totals

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through a set of inputs. I need to tally up the grouped totals.

```
var compoundedArray = new Array();

    holder.find(".dataset input").each(function(index) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var dataType = $(this).data("type");

        var localObj = {};

        localObj[dataType] = val;
        compoundedArray.push(localObj);
    });
```

I have an object like this

```
[
    {
    "growth":30
    },
    {
    "growth": 40
    },
    {
    "other": 20
    }
]
```

how do I loop through the object to produce something like

```
[
    {
        "growth": 70
    },
    {
        "other": 20
    }
]
```

if I looped over the initial array object

```
for (var i = 0; i < compoundedArray.length; i++) {
console.log(compoundedArray[i]);
}
```

how would I go about checking to ensure I don't have duplicates - and that I can tally up the results?

Comment: Is this a json object?

Comment: The bounding array seems unnecessary. Why not just one object containing the properties, rather than an object for each property?

Comment: Its a json object. yes you are right its supposed to be 70.

Comment: Utkanos please elaborate. I've got a list of inputs you see - and they are from particular groups. So I need to loop through the inputs, get their values... but now I am trying to group them accordingly

Comment: [JSON object?](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trough an Object with a for loop.
If you want to delete an item simply set it to null.

Example:

```
for(var i in compoundedArray){
    for(var j in compoundedArray){
        if(i == j){
            compoundedArray[i] += compoundedArray[j];
            compoundedArray[j] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to delete an item per say - I want to retain all items, just group together their totals

Comment: What would I do to combine the totals up?

Comment: if I looped over the initial array object

  

    for (var i = 0; i < compoundedArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(compoundedArray[i]);
    }

how would I go about checking to ensure I don't have duplicates - and that I can tally up the results?

Comment: Edited the post. Im not 100% sure if this works. But something like this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selection of data structure is a bit too complicated. Try something like.

```
var compoundedObject = {};

holder.find(".dataset input").each(function(index) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var dataType = $(this).data("type");

    //Assuming all values are integers and can be summed:
    if( compoundedObject.hasOwnProperty(dataType) )
    { 
        compoundedObject[dataType] += val;
    }
    else
    {
        compoundedObject[dataType] = val;
    }

});
```

You will end up with an object, not an array though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var add=function (a,b){ a=a||0; b=b||0; return a+b};
var input=[ {growth:30},{growth:40},{other:20} ],output=[],temp={};


$.each(input,function(i,o){
  var n;
  for(i in o)
     {n=i;break}
  temp[n]=add(temp[n],o[n]);
});

$.each(temp,function(i,o){
  var k={};
   k[i]=o;
  output.push(k)
});
```

find output at output variable.

Do not post much specific question, It might not help others.

Answer (score 0):

This works. And it's pure javascript.

```
var totals = {};

for (var i = 0; i < compoundedArray.length; i++) {
    var item = compoundedArray[i];
    for (var key in item) {
        totals[key] = (totals[key] || 0) + item[key]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var totals = [], tmp = {};
for (var i = 0; i < compoundedArray.length; i++) {
    var obj = compoundedArray[i];
    for (var j in obj) {
        tmp[j] = tmp[j] || 0;
        tmp[j] += obj[j];
    }
}

for(var k in tmp) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[k] = tmp[k];
    totals.push(obj);
}
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3UV8/)**